# libXp.so library missing on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, x11

I'm trying to install Matlab on my Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit), and it says **'the X11 library libXp.so does not exist. Matlab won't run on this machine until the library is installed'**. I followed some other forums about this problem, and the instruction was to install libxp6 (`sudo apt-get install libxp6`). I did so, but the problem still persists. I searched for the libxp.so library on my system but couldn't find it.

When tryng to run Matlab from the bin folder using `./matlab`, it says **error while loading shared libraries: libXp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

How do I install the libxp.so on ubuntu 16.04? Do I need to run any specific package for it? If libXp.so is installed, then how do I locate the .so library? Please help.

Comment: Files of type `.so` are typically compiled on the host system, you may need to find the `libXp.h` file and `make` the `libXp.so` file on your system.

Comment: I could not find libXp.h either. Is there any specific package that I need to install to get the .so file?

Comment: Try installing `libxp-dev` via `sudo apt-get install libxp-dev`?

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu 16.04 machine I did `dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so` and found out that this file is provided by the `libxp-dev` package.

So `sudo apt-get install libxp-dev` is likely to fix your problem.

Comment: Its not working. The error message says **Package libxp-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source**. Is there any other source from where I can download and install the package?

Comment: @SonaljitMukherjee Try here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libxp-dev
Also consider updating your apt repository list: https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/